# Как в C# определить длину одной табуляции в пробелах во входном потоке?

Tags: c#, консоль

Нужно заменить каждый символ табуляции во входной строке на соответствующее количество пробелов.

Мне удалось сделать то же самое, но с произвольным количеством пробелов вместо табуляции.

```
public void TabChange(string s, int i) /*s - Строка, на которой будет использоваться метод.
                                        i - Кол-во пробелов, на которое требуется заменить табуляцию.*/
{
    string newString = s.Replace("\t", new string(' ', i));
    Console.WriteLine(newString);
}
```

Comment: Не понял... `\t` - это _один_ символ. Его длина всегда `1`. / Длина табуляции может быть какой угодно в той программе, которая выводит текст. И часто её можно настраивать произвольно.

Comment: Это: `string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" ", i))` - можно заменить на `new string(' ', i)`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я спрашиваю про длину табуляции, имея в виду количество пробелов, которое он занимает в консоли. Каждая табуляция занимает разное количество, поэтому меня это и интересует.

Comment: @iiKuzmychov когда нажимал таб в консоли, расстояние, создаваемое табуляцией иногда менялось, если вводить его между словами. Винда 11 стоит, может это она подстраивает табуляцию под текст. я не знаю...

Comment: @iiKuzmychov указанный вариант я не использовал так как новичок ещё

Comment: Понятно. Табуляция не означает длину пробелов между словами, она означает позиции на экране. Как бы сетку. [Табуляция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Табуляция)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov В таком случае, можно ли узнать на каких позициях стоит табуляция?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Табуляция задаёт "сетку" вывода.
Когда встречается символ табуляции, курсор сдвигается до следующей позиции, кратной длине табуляции.
Эта длина никак не задаётся во входном потоке. Её задаёт то приложение, которое выводит текст. То есть в консоли может быть одно значение (обычно 8), в Notepad - другое, в Visual Studio - третье. В своей программе вы сами можете задать это значение.

```
using System.Text;

string text = "Это\tтекст\tс\tтабуляциями\t!";

Console.WriteLine(text);

ChangeTab(text, 8);

void ChangeTab(string s, int n)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '\t')
        {
            int tab = n - j % n;
            j += tab;
            
            sb.Append(new string(' ', tab));
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
            sb.Append(s[i]);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Здесь счётчик `i` содержит номер текущего символа во входной строке. Счётчик `j` содержит текущую позицию в выходной строке.
Когда встречается `\t`, вместо этого символа добавляем в выходную строку (StringBuilder) такое количество пробелов, чтобы текущая позиция стала кратной `n` (нашему значению табуляции). И настолько же увеличиваем `j`.

---

P.S. В некоторых приложениях для работы с текстом бывает строка табуляции, в которой можно произвольно задавать позиции. После чего при нажатии Tab сдвиг будет происходить до ближайшей позиции на шкале.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Код работает как нужно.